# Pattern for implementing on-demand loading for a bounded list

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement on-demand loading of rows using React Native, but I cannot figure out how to get a list where the user is allowed to quickly scroll to the end of the list (effectively only loading the last page) of items?

Am I correct in assuming that the ListView is not made for big bounded lists (say 5000-10000 items) that are loaded on demand, but instead made more for enormous lists that you use "infinite-scrolling", as with the Facebook news feed?

If not using the ListView, then what are my options in React Native?